# How to verify if a button is clickable in Webdriver Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify if a button is clickable, so I tried using the following :

```
def save_button_status(browser):
    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name(save_new_pass_button)
    print button.is_enabled()
```

But it is not verifying the button status, all I can understand from this code is if the button is enabled

Comment: What do you mean `it is not verifying the button status`?? is there any exception??

Comment: I want to verify if I can click on the button or not

Comment: So what are you getting at this line `button.is_enabled()`??

Comment: The answer i get is None in two different conditions.

Comment: If the button is clickable and if not i get the same answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the button is clickable you need to check two conditions: enabled and visible

```
def save_button_status(browser):
    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name(save_new_pass_button)
    print button.is_enabled() and button.is_displayed()
```